# Postgresql function throwing error "ERROR: 42702: column reference "lv" is ambiguous"

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, function

This is my function what i am using in postgresql. I want this as output datatable.

```
RETURNS TABLE(lv integer, userid integer, ccode integer, cdate date, corp_id character varying)
```

I am new to postgresql. Please suggest how i can resolve this error. Please let me know if any further information needed to answer this problem.
Thank you in advance:)

```
-- FUNCTION: public.check_login(character varying, character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.check_login(character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_login(
    username character varying,
    password character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(lv integer, userid integer, ccode integer, cdate date, corp_id character varying) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
    
AS $BODY$
begin
drop table if exists temp;                              
create table temp(lv int,userid int,ccode int,cdate date,corp_id varchar(20));                                 
                                              
insert into temp(lv,userid,ccode,cdate,corp_id)      
select lv,userid,code,CONVERT(varchar,cdate,103),corp_id from user_detail 
where uname=username and pwd =Password  and status='Active';     

return query                              
select * from temp;          
end;      
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.check_login(character varying, character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! As a starter please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please use proper markdown to make your question more understandable. You may refer: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

the ambigity meens that query engine can't guess what object to operate while having two object with the same name in one context.
replace

```
select lv,userid,code,CONVERT(varchar,cdate,103),corp_id from user_detail 
 where uname=username and pwd =Password and status='Active';
```

with

```
select ud.lv,ud.userid,ud.code,CONVERT(varchar,ud.cdate,103),ud.corp_id from user_detail AS ud
where ud.uname=username and ud.pwd=Password and ud.status='Active';
```

this will remove ambigity with same-named fields in selects and return structure